# Changing color of row depending on few properties in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, gridview, silverlight-4.0, mvvm

I have object with 3 property:

```
CouldBeWhite bool
CouldBeGreen bool
CouldBeRed bool

    If CouldBeWhite is true, then foreground of row should be white,  if
    CouldBeGreen is true, and CouldBeWhite is false, then row should be
    Green If CouldBeRed is true, and  and CouldBeWhite is false and
    CouldBeGreen is false then row should be Red In other case row
    should be blue.
```

My idea now is to have some new property at viewmodel Color, when I would count color of row.

Or maybe there is some nicer way to implement this?

Comment: That logic burns holes through my mind.  How about `enum ShouldBe { White, Green, Red }` and be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this enum to your project:-

```
public enum RowState
{
     Blue,
     Red,
     Green,
     White
}
```

Then add this property to your ViewModel:-

```
private RowState _RowState;
public RowState RowState
{
     get { return _RowState; }
     set
     {
         if (value != _RowState)
         {
               _RowState = value;
               NotifyPropertyChanged("RowState"); // Assumes typical implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged 
         }
     }
}

private void UpdateRowState()
{
    if (CouldBeWhite)
         RowState = RowState.White;
    else if (CouldBeGreen)
         RowState = RowState.Green;
    else if (CouldBeRed)
         RowState = RowState.Red;
    else
         RowState = RowState.Blue;
}
```

Call UpdateRowState when every the `CouldBeXXX` properties change.

Consider that you are probably not making the foreground white or red or green just as a whim.  There will be be some reason *why* its white, red or green.  So in your code think of a simple short name to represent those reasons and replace the color names with those more meaningful names.

Now go fetch the code for `StringToValueConverter` in this [blog](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/06/09/yet-another-blog-about-ivalueconverter.aspx).  Add an instance of this to your Xaml in the `UserControl.Resources`:

```
         <local:StringToObjectConverter x:Key="RowStateToBrush">
             <ResourceDictionary>
                 <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" x:Key="Red" />
                 <SolidColorBrush Color="Green" x:Key="Green" />
                 <SolidColorBrush Color="White" x:Key="White" />
                 <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue" x:Key="__default__" /> 
            </ResourceDictionary>
         </local:StringToObjectConverter>
```

You can bind on a `TextBlock`:

```
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeTextProperty}"  Foreground="{Binding RowState, Converter={StaticResource RowStateToBrush}}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be cleaner to implement this logic in a custom value converter.  Something like:

```
  public class RowColorConverter : IValueConverter
        {
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                var myObj = value as MyObjectType();

                if (myObj.CouldBeWhite)
                {
                    return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
                }
                if (myObj.CouldBeGreen )
                {
                    return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                }
                if (myObj.CouldBeRed )
                {
                    return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                }
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);

            }  

           public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```